# A conjecture on tensor product vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vectors, tensor-products, conjectures

Consider a real vector space $V^{(1)}\otimes V^{(2)}$ where $\otimes$ is the tensor product. Product vectors are of the form $v_1\otimes v_2$ where $v_1\in V^{(1)}$, $v_2\in V^{(2)}$, anything else is a non-product vector. I conjecture the following

I have a set of product vectors $a_i\otimes b_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$ that sum to make a product vector $A\otimes B$, $A\otimes B=\sum_i \alpha_i a_i \otimes b_i$ where $\alpha_i$ are real, non-zero constants and there are no repetitions of $a_i$. All of these product vectors must have $b_i= \lambda \, B$ $\forall$ $i$, where $\lambda$ is some non-zero real.

I believe this is true, but am not sure how to proceed. For example, if $n=2$, then $A\otimes B=a_1\otimes b_1 + a_2 \otimes b_2$ is not a product vector unless $a_1=a_2$ or $b_1 =b_2$, and then it is clear that either $a_1=a_2=A$ or $b_1=b_2=B$

Comment: You can show your vector space has basis $v \otimes w$ where $v$ runs over the basis of $V^1$ and $w$ over the basis of $V^2$. That's probably how it was defined actually, since you have this question tagged with linear algebra.

Comment: Is the $+$ a $\oplus$ (direct sum), or just a sum?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud $+$ is the sum, not the direct sum.

Comment: @3-in-441 sounds interesting. yes they do have such a basis, you can assume. How does this help prove / disprove the conjecture?

Comment: I guess you mean that $A$  is some vector of $V^{(1)}\otimes V^{(2)}$, isn't it?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. What do you mean by $\propto$ in this context? If the products you talk about are tensor products, then they don't admit projections functions.

Comment: @RobArthan by $x\propto y$ I mean $x$ is $y$ multiplied by a scalar. You are correct about projections, that was from a previous framing of the question and has now been removed.

Comment: Right. So your question is about tensor products. Please rephrase it in terms of the tensor product construction bearing in mind the difference between tensor products and direct products. If you do that carefully, you may find that you can answer the question for yourself. Calculating the dimensions of $V \otimes W$ and $V \times W$ may give you some useful clues.

Comment: @jdizzle: I have already put enough effort in answering your original question, keeping up with your comments and trying to help you reformulating. Now you are asking me to delete my answer (which referred to the initial form of your question and has been already accepted by you). I think this is unfair for me and disruptive for the site itself. This is why I advised you to ask ask a new question. Letting alone that the new form of your question is rather vague (again). you are leaving me no other choice than to flag your post (this means: asking moderators intervention to handle it).

Comment: @KonKan apologies

Comment: No it is not something personal to apologise for, to me. It has to do with the site itself. think about it a little: Why should someone bother to answering if you are going to change it again so that the new answer will not apply again?

Comment: I'll flag it and the reason is that I do not know how to handle such a situation. See you around in some more constructive QnA ;)

Comment: @KonKan for what its worth I agree with everything you say, please do, and thank you for your input. It has helped me / saved me a lot of time.

Comment: thank you for you reasonable and kind response as well ;)

Comment: If someone has taken the time to answer your question, do not modify it in such a way it deems the answers useless. Please, post another question instead. I will revert to the original question. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, $X\otimes Y = P\otimes Q + A$ then yor statement:

> $A$ is a linear sum of terms of this form ...

is valid (by definition). But the rest are not. Take for example $\mathbb{R}^4$, and a basis $\mathbf{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4}$. Let
$$
A=\mathbf{e_1\otimes e_2+e_3\otimes e_4}
$$
Then  $A$ has none of the forms: $P\otimes (\dots )$ or  $(\dots )\otimes Q$ or  $X\otimes (\dots )$ or  $(\dots )\otimes Y$

Thus, your conjecture is not true in general.

Comment: $A$ is a subspace, not a single vector.

Comment: No it is not. Read the OP carefully please.

Comment: Apologies, @KonKan is correct that A is a vector. The confusion was down to my poor phrasing of the question

Comment: @ Daniel Robert-Nicoud: I think it would be reasonable to cancel your downvote.

Comment: @KonKan could you elaborate on this please? Is the a counter example or do you agree to some extent with the conjecture? If $A=e_1\otimes e_2+e_3\otimes e_4$, and we add a product vector $B$ to it to make another product vector, then the conjecture would imply that $B$ must be something like $B=e_1\otimes x - e_3 \otimes e_4$, etc. The equation can also be phrased as ``I have a general vector $A$, and ai add a product vector to it $B$. The result is a product vector $C$. Knowing $B$ and $C$, how does this constrain $A$?''

Comment: @KonKan Done. The question is still unclearly stated, however.

Comment: @jdizzle: as I said in my answer, I think that your conjecture is not true. In the sense that the cases $P\otimes (\dots )$ or  $(\dots )\otimes Q$ or  $X\otimes (\dots )$ or  $(\dots )\otimes Y$ are rejected by the counterexample in my post, while the "linear sums of terms of this form" holds (by definition) so it cannot be considered a conjecture.

Comment: @ Daniel Robert-Nicoud, I agree that the whole statement is a little "messy" however it clearly states that "$A\in V^{(1)}\otimes V^{(2)}$". In any case, thank you for your immediate response.

Comment: @jdizzle, regarding the question posed in your last comment, I have to admit that I did not really understand what you are asking. Maybe it would be a good idea to work on it a little bit and pose it as a new question.

Comment: @KonKan and Daniel, that you both for your helpful input. I will rephrase the question is a more clear way.

Comment: @KonKan the question has been updated significantly, would you mind taking down this answer as it no longer applies? Many thanks

Comment: @jdizzle As I commented above, avoid updating the question significantly, that is, in such a way that a current answer no longer applies. Instead, post another question.

Comment: @KonKan Please roll back to the version of the post that goes with this answer.